# SMS-draft on incoming call

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, lock-screens, calls, htc-wildfire

I have a tiny problem with my Android on HTC Wildfire. When I got incoming call and my screen is blocked, I have to move a ring to unblock and answer the phone; but if I move this ring fast enough and my phone doesn't capture my movement, I get a cancelled call and a sms-draft 'Sorry, I'm busy' etc. The problem is: is there any way to disable this option to have an sms-draft? I'd like to have not a possibility to slide to sms-draft with call cancel. My Android version is 2.3.5

Comment: This might be a hardware limitation, maybe the resolution of the touch digitizer is too low for your fast finger and it detects 2 taps instead. You can try to change to a different lock screen / answer screen which uses sth. different. Also custom ROMs usually come with many options for the lockscreen feature

Comment: Some phones have the capability to edit/remove the predefined call-refusal messages, see if you can find them and remove all, maybe this will disable the SMS sending.